# append object in javascript

Tags: javascript, sails.js

In below my code, I try to append the populate in mainQuery object. If I pass only types, then I get the expected result and query also build. If I pass both types and sub category, then query was broken and object is not added as per expected query bellow. Kindly give solution for this ?

```js
mainQuery = Category.find();

if(req.param('types')) {
    searchKey = "types";
    typesObj.where = {
        id: 1
    };

    mainQuery.populate(searchKey, typesObj);
}   

if(req.param('subcat')) {
    searchkeySubCat = "subcategory";
    typesSubcat.where = {
        id: 1
    };

    mainQuery.populate(searchkeySubCat, typesSubcat);
}

mainQuery.exec(function (err, category) {

});
```

**Expected Query as below**

```js
Category.find().populate('types', {where: {id:1}}).populate('subcategory', {where: {id:1}}).exec(function (err, res) { 
    console.log(res)
})
```

Comment: What happen when you delete de where inside populate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try as below:

```
function _getWhereClause(key, value) {
   return {where: {key: value}};
}

if (req.param('types')) {
    populateKey = 'types';
    mainQuery.populate(populateKey, _getWhereClause('id', 1));
}
// Do the same for any number of populate you want
```

At last execute the query:

```
mainQuery.exec(function (err, category) {

});
```

Check the documentation for more understanding- http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/waterline-orm/queries/populate

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will check and update you. In meantime, can you answer my another question which is in Stackover flow find the below url ?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37608302/sailsjs-using-through-relation-how-to-get-the-value-of-non-related-models

Answer (score 0):

What are you tryin to is basically method chaining with `mainQuery` object . So basically you are forming one query and later on use that query . I will suggest that you make this query as a string .
for eg.

```
mainQuery = "Category.find().";
mainQuery+= "populate("+searchKey+","+ typesObj+").";
mainQuery +="populate("+searchkeySubCat+","+ typesSubcat+").";
mainQuery +="exec(function (err, res) { console.log(res)});";
```

So when you will access mainQuery you will have :

```
   Category.find().populate('types', {where:     {id:1}}).populate('subcategory', {where: {id:1}}).exec(function (err, res) { 
console.log(res)
 });
```